# Affine variety versus projective

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-varieties

I need to prove that a point $P$ in a projective curve $C$ is non-singular if and only if its local ring $\mathcal{O}_P$ in a Discrete Valuation Ring.
I know this is true on a affine variety. 
Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove a different point Q from the projective curve C. Them you get a a new  affine variety (curve). Now the local ring at P both for this affine curve and the given projective curve are the same (or isomorphic).

That is local ring of a point of a variety depends  only on (any) affine open subset containing that point. In the case of manifolds the local ring is defined by using germs of differentiable/analytic functions which depends only on the open subset containing that point.